# Load resources in gadgets in Jira

Tags: css, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I've made an Add-on which is a custom field.
The style of the text in the field changes depending on the properties of an issue. 
I check which style should the text have in the .java file and I pass the html class in a variable called $indicator to the velocity template:

```
#if( ${value} )
    <span class="$indicator">${value}</span>
#end
```

It works perfect everywhere but in gadgets. When I add this field to a table showing issues in a dashboard, the html code is correct, but it doesn't find the css resource. This is because gadgets are inside an iframe.
How can I make the iframe have a reference to the stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say exactly which gadget you were using, but try adding the following context within your `<web-resource>` module:

```
<context>jira.webresources:issue-table</context>
```

The above should work for at least Assigned to Me, Filter Results, In Progress, Voted, and Watched in JIRA 6.1+.

If that does not work, you might also try:

```
<context>com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common-lite</context>
```

If that general context doesn't work, you can look for which exact contexts are `#requireContext`'ed by the specific gadget you are trying to use, and then make sure that your web-resource is listed in that context. You can figure this out by looking at the gadget's XML and then searching for the `#requireContext`. (You can find the gadget XMLs inside $JIRA_DATA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/transformed-plugins/jira-gadgets-plugin-*.jar)

Comment: Oh I didin't know I could use more than one context. Added the first you said (I already had atl.general), and now it works everywhere. If I remove atl.genral then it only works in gadgets.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with JIRA 7 the Answer of Scott Dudley is no longer working.  `#requireContext` was replaced with a `#requireResource` within the Atlassian sources of this gadget.
As it affects our plugin, I created a [Improvement Request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-61714) to make that possible again